# Input Box doesnt have ID names

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a vba macro that could copy data from excel file to a webpage.
However, the 2 input boxes where I am going to paste data doesn't have ID name.

The 2 input boxes where I need to paste data is just within the same row.

Input Box 1 - Row 3, Col 3
Input Box 2 - Row 3, Col 5.

```
<input class="JSTextfield" maxlength="29" autocomplete="off" type="text" tabindex="2" style="width: 186px; text-align: left;" originalstring="" prevwidth="186">
```

Comment: <input class="JSTextfield" maxlength="29" autocomplete="off" type="text" tabindex="2" style="width: 186px; text-align: left;" originalstring="" prevwidth="186">

Comment: You can use getElementsByTagName or getElementsByClassName to return a collection of elements and from there, see which item is the input box that you want.